# How to change copy/paste selector popup color in React Native with Native Base?

Tags: ios, react-native, native-base

How to change copy/paste selector popup color in React Native with Native Base?

I have light and dark mode in my app but the selector is showing in light mode, and IOS is in dark mode.
I have default dark mode in navigation container and in the native base provider.

```
return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <SafeAreaProvider>
          <NavigationContainer onReady={layoutRootView} theme={DarkTheme}>
            <NativeBaseProvider theme={theme}>
              <AnimatedAppLoader image={SplashImage}>
                <Navigation />
              </AnimatedAppLoader>
            </NativeBaseProvider>
          </NavigationContainer>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
      </ApolloProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
```

[image: phoot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by adding userInterfaceStyle in the app.json config in Expo.

```
"userInterfaceStyle": "dark"
```